# Slider control for boolean values?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm new in the wp8 development world. I hope you can help me with the following:
I would like to implement some UI where the user can change some configuration values of the app. For example, let say there is a point asking for notifications:

Enable notifications:       [Yes/No]

So, my idea is that the part where the "Yes/No" is displayed put some kind of control for those boolean values. Almost the same way as: when you go to configurations -> wifi -> activated 
There there is a control for that.

I'm trying with the slider control to see if I can do that but not pretty sure if is the correct way.

Any clue would be very helpful

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you about ToggleSwitch control from [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291) (for WP7) and [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/releases/view/106971) for WP8?
If yes, this article will be helpful: [WP7 ToggleSwitch in depth | key concepts and API](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-toggleswitch-in-depth--key-concepts-and-api)